# Plotting a subplot on top of another plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I need to plot several plots along a sloped line at different positions.

For example, if I:

```
plot(0:200,'k');
plotpts = 5:5:200;
```

I would like to be able to plot a smaller plot at each of my plotpts on top of the original 0:200 line.

I know you can use `hold on` and plot over top that way, but I need to change my origin each time. Does anyone have any suggestions? I would really like to stay in matlab. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate your "smaller plot at each of my plotpts"?

Comment: Plot, for example, a sine wave at plot(plotpts(1)). For each element of plotpts. Kind of like using the black plot as a background for the smaller foreground plot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a flexible way I usually do it:

```
plot(1:10, 'k')
plotpts = 2:2:8;

mainbox = get(gca, 'Position');
xlims = get(gca, 'XLim');
ylims = get(gca, 'Ylim');

for i=1:length(plotpts)
    originx = mainbox(1) + (plotpts(i) - xlims(1)) * (mainbox(3)) / (xlims(2) - xlims(1));
    originy = mainbox(2) + (plotpts(i) - ylims(1)) * (mainbox(4)) / (ylims(2) - ylims(1));

    axes('position', [originx originy 0.1 0.1], 'Color', 'none')

    % Do some plotting here...
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's quite a bit of work, but you probably want to use the `axes` command.  A figure window can host any number of axes, where each axes has it's own position, data, annotations, color etc.

The most difficult thing for the application you describe is that each axis position needs to be defined in the coordinate frame of the underlying figure, which means that some math may be required to create the illusion that the axis is correctly positioned within a parent axes/

For example, if you first create a simple plot

```
figure(1234); clf;
plot(1:10, rand(1,10),'.k-','linewidth',5);
xlim([1 10]);
ylim([0 1]);
set(gca,'color','y');  %This just helps demonstrate the next steps
```

You can place another axis directly on top of the first, and then

```
ha = axes('position',[.2 .3 .1 .1])
plot(linspace(0,2*pi,100), sin(linspace(0,2*pi,100)), 'b-')
xlim([0 2*pi])
```

You can adjust the the properties of the inset axis to suit your particular needs, for example

```
set(ha,'color','none');  %A transparent axis
set(ha,'xtick',[],'ytick',[]);  %Remove tick labels 
title(ha,'This is an inset plot')
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the command [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html) not what you're looking for?

Comment: No, not unless I can subplot directly on top of another graph. And at an exact point on that graph's contents (i.e. when x = some number)